# Change the default number of segments when creating a circle on LineString Layer

Tags: qgis-3

Default created circle always has 361 vertices. How can I change it?
QGIS 3.28.4

My basic task is to get intersection of two distances. I try to do it by creating two intersection circles from two points where radiuses represent distances. But when I do it I am losing accuracy of intersection distances about a few millimeters.

Comment: If you're worrying about millimeter accuracy in geographic data, you aren't likely to make much progress with any publicly available dataset, where accuracy is often measured in tens of meters.